# Simultaneously input and output in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

So I'm trying to make a script in NodeJS that can take output from a spawned child process and print it to the console, and take input from the user and send it to the child process and press enter. I currently have this setup:

```
function log(data) {
  process.stdout.write(data.toString())
}

childProcess.stdout.on('data', log)
childProcess.stderr.on('data', log)

let rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question("Command>> ", cmd => {
  childProcess.stdin.write(cmd + '\n')
})
```

But if I don't give it an answer by the time the child process gives its first output, it logs where my cursor is: on the question. I would also like it to keep the input prompt at the bottom if possible, but it's not too important.

How would I go about doing this? All help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I would hope that `readline` has a way of outputting text above its cursor, i.e. it should manage the screen and you should only interact with the output through `rl` not by directly writing to stdout. However, I fear there's no way to do that

Comment: I've just had a look, and no, I couldn't see one. I have however found a possible workaround: every time the `childProcess` writes to stdout, running `readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, process.stdout.rows + 1)`. I'll try it later, if it works, I'll post it as an answer. Thanks for your help though, because I'd never have found that if I hadn't taken a closer look at `readline!

Comment: Does that work for multiline questions? And does it work when readline does not prompt anything?

Comment: I don't know if it works when it's not prompting anything, and I know it only works if the prompt option for `rl` is set to nothing (`''`), as my program is constantly prompting from the user, so they can type a command whenever. It doesn't work for multiline questions, no, because as soon as you press enter it submits the question. You might be able to stitch multiple lines together though, and get a multiline question that way. I hope that's clear :)

Comment: I meant `rl.question("Multiline\nPrompt?", …)`, not the user pressing enter. But anyway, you might want to [post your solution as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Oh, right, I haven't tried that, I wouldn't know.
I just did do , thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, thanks to the comment from @Bergi, I had a closer look at `readline`, and found a different approach to it. Here's what I did:

```
function log(data) {
  readline.cursorTo(process.stdout, 0, process.stdout.rows + 1)
  process.stdout.write(data.toString())
}

childProcess.stdout.on('data', log)
childProcess.stderr.on('data', log)

let rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
  prompt: ''
})

rl.on('line', (line) => {
  childProcess.stdin.write(line.trim() + '\n')
  rl.prompt()
})
```

I'll admit, it's not the best, but it's all I need :) Thanks Bergi!